# How to set height of magicsuggest?

Tags: php, jquery, magicsuggest

I am using magicsuggest for tagging and i want to set maximum height of magicsuggest.

if i tag more words inside magicsuggest then vertical scroll bar must be drop inside of the magicsuggest.

Html :

```
<div id="magicsuggest"></div>
```

Js :

```
$('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
   data: ['Paris', 'New York', 'Gotham']
});
```

Dependencies :

```
<link href="css/magicsuggest-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/magicsuggest-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have both **magicsuggest.css** and **magicsuggest-min.css**.

In **magicsuggest.css** and you can found **.ms-res-ctn** (perhaps line no : 111) class, then set **max-height**.

If you have only **magicsuggest-min.css** then find that class and set **max-height**.

If you found any difficulties you can ping me.

Hope it will help you!